# Failed to configure DataSource:'url' attribute is not specified & no embedded datasource configure Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating first spring boot project using Eclipse, I have generated project with help of Spring Initilizr. now I am getting this error "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class Action: Consider the following: If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
[Printscreen Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cweG2.png)
[Printscreen application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf6EB.png)

This is the code that I have written.

I am creating my first spring boot project and at the start of learning phase I got this error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: simply, you add some dependecy that need DB, so SpringBoot, that auto-configure almost all thing you need, ask you to explicit DB !

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.properties or application.yml file: Make sure you have correctly configured the database URL, username, password, etc. For instance, if you're using an H2 database, your application.properties should contain configurations similar to the following:

```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
   spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
   spring.datasource.username=sa
   spring.datasource.password=password
   spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

If you want to use an embedded database (like H2, HSQL, or Derby), ensure you have added it to your project's dependencies. For Maven, if you're using H2, your pom.xml should include:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

remove the datasource auto configuration for now if you do not have any database integration yet. You can add them later when you have your database

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/